# When outputting multiple sheets using ods tagsets.ExcelXP and body=test.html it doesn't work as intended

Tags: excel, sas, output, worksheet, sas-ods

I am outputting several tables into several worksheets in one xml type Excel spreadsheet.

The problem I am having is that out of the six worksheets I am outputting, the final four are using a body=test.html as well, to allow certain style formats to work (which only work if I use the body= command). When it runs however, the first two worksheets are output and the final four are not.

eg.

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file='example.xls' options(...sheet_name=sheet1...);

proc report;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp options(...sheet_name=sheet2...);
proc tabulate;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp body='test1.html' options(...sheet_name=sheet3...);
proc report;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp body='test2.html' options(...sheet_name=sheet4...);
proc report;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp body='test3.html' options(...sheet_name=sheet5...);
proc report;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp body='test4.html' options(...sheet_name=sheet6...);
proc report;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

The first two are output fine, but the final four are not. I have tried placing the *body='test.html'* for each ods tagsets.excelxp line, but it doesn't work and just outputs the first sheet. I cannot skip out the ods tagsets.excelxp lines as I need different options for each sheet...is there a way to output these in the same spreadsheet? I am not allowed to use VBA or any manual interventions.

Comment: What are you expecting the body=... html statement to do? The code doesn't make sense honestly. You use sheet_interval to control where output goes, i.e. same sheet/different sheets.

Comment: Hmmm interesting...how do I then use different options without using another ods tagsets.excelxp line? If I use that sheet_interval, then where do I place the sheet_name for each worksheet, and does this mean if I place the body= on the first one, they will all output in the same spreadsheet?

Comment: You can't mix ods tagsets.excelxp and ods html commands in the same output. When you say certain styles don't work in Tagsets.excelpxp can you expand on that? Perhaps that code can be fixed.

Comment: I have no idea what `body=` does in a `tagsets.excelxp` statement, but anything it does is almost certainly an accident.

Answer (score 0):

You can't output tagsets.ExcelXP to an HTML file and expect it to work as the XML would.

You need to output the first two `proc tabulate` to the ExcelXP tagset destination, close the tagset, open a new HTML destination for each HTML file, run `proc report`, and the close the HTML.

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file='example.xls' options(...sheet_name=sheet1...);
proc report;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp options(...sheet_name=sheet2...);
proc tabulate;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;


ods html body='test1.html' ;
proc report;
run;
ods html close ;

ods html body='test1.html' ;
proc report;
run;
ods html close ;

ods html body='test2.html' ;
proc report;
run;
ods html close ;

ods html body='test4.html' ;
proc report;
run;
ods html close ;
```

Comment: That gives me separate output for the four last ones though, whereas I want them to all be separate worksheets in one spreadsheet output. The reason I am using the body= is because certain border commands don't work with excelXP as they should when output into excel, so for example, I want some borders to be white, but they aren't. With the body= it works... but then means they aren't output into the same output spreadsheet

Comment: Post an example (using `sashelp.class`) of the formatting issue you're trying to solve, and we'll try to help you with that. This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Several of us have significant experience solving Excel Tagsets problems.